# Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove that no group of order $2p$ is simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory, normal-subgroups

*Attempted proof:*

Let $G$ be a group of order $2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime. By Sylow's First Theorem, $G$ contains $p$-subgroups of order $2$ and order $p$. Because both $2$ and $p$ are prime, there exist at most only one Sylow $2$-subgroup and only one Sylow $p$-subgroup. By a corollary, $|Syl_2(G)|$ and $|Syl_p(G)|$ are both normal in $G$. Hence, $G$ is not simple.

Comment: I'm confused--why doesn't GA316's argument work?Also, Glacier, your argument does not work, else your group is cyclic. If both the $p$ and $2$ Sylow subgroups are normal, then $G$ is a product of them, and so cyclic.

Comment: The statement "because both 2 and p are prime, there exist at most only one Sylow 2-subgroup..." is false. (Look at $S_3$, which has $3$ Sylow 2 subgroups). Your argument should be 'the number of Sylow p-subgroups is kp+1, and kp+1 | 2p, hence kp+1=1. So the Sylow p-subgroup is normal.

Comment: @Amudhan "The number of Sylow $p$-subgroups is $kp+1$" is Third Sylow's Theorem,. But how do we know that the number (rather than size) of Sylow $p$-subgroups divides the order of $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any group $G$, a subgroup $H<G$ of index $2$ is normal (list right and left cosets and draw a conclusion).

If $p\mid |G|$, $G$ has a subgroup with $p$ elements by Cauchy's theorem. But if $|G|=2p$ a subgroup with $p$ elements will have index $2$ by Lagrange's theorem. Thus .....

Comment: Why did you get an upvote, when GA316 said the same thing and got a downvote??

Comment: @AlexYoucis : I don't think that I'm the right person to ask this question. I think it's the simplest way to solve the problem, if he hadn't deleted his answer he (she?) would have got my upvote.

Comment: Fair enough :) +1

Comment: @AlexYoucis I meant to upvote GA316's answer but I clicked the wrong arrow and inadvertently gave it a downvote.

Comment: Indeed, this seems like the simplest way, except that we can even avoid Cauchy as follows: If all non-identity elements have order $2$, then the group is abelian and not simple (as the order is not $2$). Thus, we can assume for the purpose of this that it does have an element of order $p$.

Comment: @glacier : I believe downvotes can be reverted. If GA316 is reading this and wants to undelete his answer, I promise an upvote.

Comment: @AndreaMori And I was also about to undo my accidental downvote, then they deleted their comment. So instead I got a message that basically said "cannot undo votes to deleted comments".

Comment: When Cauchy's theorem was used, I kinda used Sylow's first theorem (the one that asserts containing a subgroup of order $p^k$ instead of order $p$) ... is that also acceptable? (My teacher said that Sylow's first theorem is "stronger" than Cauchy's theorem.)

Comment: @glacier Indeed, Sylow's theorem implies Cauchy's theorem in a fairly easy way, so in that sense it is stronger. As long as the text has covered both at this point, either will be fine to use in such an exercise.

Comment: @GA316, you should undelete your correct hint to this question's solution. I'm sure you'll get quite a few upvotes (go guess who's the silly one who downvoted your correct hint...). As for me, I'm voting to undelete it and I'll upvote it then.